# Faking a dead LiPo cell with a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, batteries, lipo

I have several old smart phones and small laptop computers with dead batteries (LiIon, LiPo).

These battery cells charge to max 4.2V.

When I remove the batteries, these devices won't power on anymore, even if connected to a PSU / charger (in my case 5V for the laptop, USB for the phones).

Is it possible to just connect a capacitor (1F, 5.5V) to the charger circuit that connected directly to the battery terminals to fake a battery, so I can run these devices while powered externally?

Or do I need further parts to fake a battery and not damage the circuitry?

Comment: Quite possibly. Depends what exactly the device is doing with the battery. An exact answer might not be possible without knowing the circuit in the device.

Comment: use a 4.2V power supply (better than using capacitor) on the battery terminals to fake the battery. 5.5V might be too much. Why use a capacitor rathen than power supply from the first place?

Comment: The power supply was my initial plan, but then I thought maybe it's easy enough to "fake" a battery. But yes , i see, I will be better off with a buck converter set to 4.2V feeding into the charge circuit where the battery terminals were originally connected.